# You tube video can not display in the web site

Tags: youtube

I am trying to embed the you tube video in my web site . I would like to embed this video in my site for example http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ma4k5sEdBDo

It works well when I use the url http://www.youtube.com/embed/Ma4k5sEdBDo in the iframe, but it is not working when I use the url http://youtu.be/Ma4k5sEdBDo ( that got from the share option). I would like to enter the url from the share option.

This is my code

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="{$movieDetails.url}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Thanks in advance,

Sunil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to embed your channel, all you need to do is copy then paste the following code in another web-page.

```
<script src="http://www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://www.google.com/ig/modules/youtube.xml&up_channel=YourChannelName&synd=open&w=320&h=390&title=&border=%23ffffff%7C3px%2C1px+solid+%23999999&output=js"></script>
```

Make sure to replace the **YourChannelName** with your actual channel name.

For example: if your channel name were **CaliChick94066** your channel embed code would be:

```
<script src="http://www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://www.google.com/ig/modules/youtube.xml&up_channel=CaliChick94066&synd=open&w=320&h=390&title=&border=%23ffffff%7C3px%2C1px+solid+%23999999&output=js"></script>
```

Please look at the following links:

[YouTube on your site](http://www.youtube.com/youtubeonyoursite)

[Embed YouTube Channel](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/youtube/thread?tid=4c414f514bc3f690&hl=en)

You just have to name the URL to your channel name. Also you can play with the height and the border color and size. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your replay. But I would like to add individual videos, no need to get videos from a channel . I would like to provide a facility to the users to add embed their own youtube video URLS.